# apache rewrite query string conditional

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

I currently have this apache config code for a drupal installation (excerpt).

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.51\.153\.4$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(admin|user/(password)) [NC]
RewriteRule . . [F]
```

The purpose is to prevent access to the admin section unless you have the specified ip.

I would now like to add some logic to the condition:
If you are trying to reach this url: /admin/build/panels/*
then that should be ok, from all ip's. Is it possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more `RewriteCond` to your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/build/panels/ [NC]
```

This would prevent your forbidden `[F]` rule to fire for a given URL path and its sub-directories.